# Equivalent of ternary operator in R

Tags: r

In C++ the ternary operator enables shorthand conditional assignment of variable values:

```
x = y > 2 ? y : 2;
```

In R, the closest operation of which I am aware is the following:

```
ifelse(y > 2, x <- y, x <- 2)
```

It just feels clumsy and looks OO awkward to type `x` twice on the same line, especially when doing this dozens of times. Is there a cleaner method for conditional assignment in R?

Comment: `x <- ifelse(y > 2, y, 2)`

Comment: @missuse please don't confuse `if` and `ifelse`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest (in fact, exact) equvalent would be:

```r
x = if (y > 2) y else 2
```

Or, if you want to perform a vectorised test and assignment:

```r
x = ifelse(y > 2, y, 2)
```

(For `y = 1 : 5`, this yields `2  2  3  4  5`.)

The important point is that, unlike in C++, (almost) **every statement R is an expression with a value**. C++ needs the conditional operator because `if` isn’t an expression. But in R it is, and the value of an `if (‹condition›) ‹true› [else ‹false›]` expression is the value of either the ‹true› or the ‹false› sub-expression, depending on whether its ‹condition› evaluates to `TRUE` (and if the `false` branch is missing, its value is `NULL`).